# .NET PDF libraries that allow page to page text flow

Tags: .net, pdf

I'm looking into various PDF generation libraries for .NET that will allow me to flow multi column text from one page to another. After looking at numerous product information sheets I don't seem to be able to find one that does this.

I'm kind of resigned to looking at automating the process through .NET with an XML import into an InDesign template but would massively prefer to use a .NET library instead ofhaving to use the InDesign COM object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Aspose for .Net - this is a commercial library be it said and a marginally costly one at that.

Comment: I confirm, you can do that with Aspose.Net.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this for sure. The license might be prohibitively expensive though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PdfSharp. I have used it a few times and its always met my requirements. Its free and available via NuGet